# PHP Query Update Data

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error im getting:

UPDATE problemas SET situacao='Concluido' WHERE id=? SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

I tried a lot of things and only managed to work with the code bellow thanks to everyone

Comment: Is the id correct? In the code you're using 2, but on the screenshot it is 22. BTW, it would be much easier and safer to handle that task with existing database wrapper. Now you're responsible of sanitizing user input against SQL injection.

Comment: i saw that i and i change it to ? so it can read any row

Comment: Please show your PHP code. You can share code on https://PHPize.online

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are close with your own answer. As Slava Rozhnev points out though your code is open to SQL injection. In your question you are using a placeholder in your query. When you prepare the statement you tell PDO: `whatever I put in there, do not execute it, it is just data`. After preparing you can bind values to the placeholders. This can be done with [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) or [bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or even with [execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "oil";

$id = 'id';
$sql = "UPDATE problemas SET situacao='Concluido' WHERE id=?";
try {
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $id);

    $stmt->execute();

    header("Location:verTodos.php");
} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$link = null;

?>
```

The line `$stmt->bindValue(1, $id)` reads the current value and replaces the placeholder with it. If you were to use a loop, and the `$id` would be everchanging you could use `$stmt-bindParam(1, $id)` this reads the current value of the `$id` variable at the moment of executing the query. Another option would be to remove the `bindValue` call and let `execute` bind the values. This can be done by adding an array of values as parameter to the `execute` call. In your case that would be `$stmt->execute([$id])`. My personal preference goes to execute for that, since it is much clearer than adding a load of bindValue calls before the execute.

Also, note that I have moved the assignment of the `$sql` variable outside of the try-catch block. This is because you want to use the variable in the catch, which might be problematic if the PDOException got thrown by the constructor of PDO(on the line `$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);`

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "oil";

$id = 'id';

try {
  $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

  $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql = "UPDATE problemas SET situacao='Concluido' WHERE id=$id";

  $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->execute();

  header("Location:verTodos.php");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$link = null;

?>
```

Thats what you need to do to solve

UPDATE problemas SET situacao='Concluido' WHERE id=? SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: This code open for SQL injection! Never do variable concatenation in SQL query!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).